# How to display a progress icon when clicking "Show more" on a CellTree?

Tags: gwt, cell

I'm using the CellTree for the very first time and slowly getting a hang of it.
Right now I'm struggling how to display a progress icon (just like when opening a tree node) beside the "Show more" text when clicking on it.
Any ideas?
I guess it is a common problem that users are clicking on "Shore more" multiple times if they do not get any visual feedback - which leads to multiple server calls and a bunch of duplicated nodes (in my case).

Answer (score 0):

Any time you send a call off to the server, you know that you are making the call. Likewise, you will get a call back into your code, whether it succeeded or failed.

For the sake of this example, I'm assuming you are using something like GWT-RPC (since the question doesn't specify):

```
// field to track if we're loading
private boolean isLoading = false

//...

// inside a method which needs to load data:
if (isLoading) {
  return;//don't attempt to load again
}
isLoading = true;
//just before we start the call, show the loading indicator
loadingIndicator.flash();//or whatever you'd like to make it do
//then start the request
service.getMyData(param1, param2, new AsyncCallback<MyData> () {
  public void onSuccess(MyData response) {
    //loading was successful, so stop the loading marker
    isLoading = false;
    loadingIndicator.success();

    //do something with the data
    //...
  }
  public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
    //loading stopped, but it was an error, tell the user
    isLoading = false;
    loadingIndicator.error();
  }
});
```